# Sharepoint InputFormTextBox: cannot change text color

Tags: sharepoint

I have a custom sharepoint aspx form that has an InputFormTextBox with RichText property set to true.

In browser when I change the color of the text I receive a javascript error:

Message: 'g_elemRTELastTextAreaConverted' is null or not an object
Line: 2509
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://myhost/_layouts/1033/form.js

what can be the reason for this

Comment: Can you provide details about how you're changing the text color? It's likely relevant to the error you're receiving.

Comment: I highlight the text and press on the text color button in the text box toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it.

In my code behind i used to refrence the scripts like this:

```
string script2="<script type=\"text/javascript\"language=\"javascript\"
src=\"/_layouts/1033/init.js\"></script>";
string script3="<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"/_layouts/1033/core.js\"></script>";
string script4="<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"/_layouts/1033/form.js\"></script>";

            cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key2", script2, false);
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key3", script3, false);
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "key4", script4, false);
```

when I removed these references everything worked fine
thanks